# Element with the least norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $W$ be the set of points $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, for which $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = 1$. Knowing that $W$ is convex and closed, find an element in $W$ which has the least norm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.Please consider adding what you have tried so far,your thoughts and approaches etc. to the body of the question.That way,others can help you better and will be more willing to do so.Furthermore,they won't need to repeat things you already know about.You will also find  that imperative sentences in a question might annoy some people.Please make necessary edits to make the question more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w_{0}=\frac{1}{n}(1,1,1,\cdots,1)$. Then $w_{0} \in W$. Furthermore, $(w,w_{0})=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $w \in W$. Equivalently, $(w-w_{0},w_{0})=0$ for all $w \in W$, which gives
$$
                \|w\|^{2}=\|(w-w_{0})+w_{0}\|^{2}=\|w-w_{0}\|^{2}+\|w_{0}\|^{2}.
$$
So $\|w\| \ge \|w_{0}\|$ with equality iff $w=w_{0}$.